# How to Make Relation to three Tables, SugarOrm

Tags: android, relational-database, relationship, sugarorm

There is 3 tables extends SugarRecord(SugarOrm Library) in **Android**
1. UserItem
2. AccountItem
3. CommunityItem

Every One of users have **One** Account, And **One** table to keep user's Address,Phone, Some Social Address, ...

the Code i used is:

**UserItem:**

```
int fieldId;
int userId;
String name;
String family;
String cover;
String avatar;

// ==================== RelationShips ...
AccountItem accountItem;
CommunityItem communityItem;
// How to define Get/Set To Relation Items
```

**AccountItem:**

```
int userId;
String authKey;
String authValue;
String userName;
String email;
String password;
String type;
String token;
String url;
String createDate;
String updateDate;
```

**CommunityItem:**

```
int userId;
String phone;
String mobile;
String facebook;
String instagram;
String linkedIn;
String summer;
String website;
String url;
String margin;
String state;
String city;
String address;
```

But it doesn't work, How to define relation to this example?

Answer (score 1):

One to one relationships are not currently supported in SugarORM, and one to many relationships aren't particularly well implemented:

> - We will try to improve how we handle one-to-many relationships
> - One-to-one relationship doesn't work yet

*Source: [Sugar ORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/creation.html)*

Answer (score 1):

You can set the objects in the Java code:

```
UserItem user = new User():
//...
//Setters
//..

AccountItem accountItem = new AccountItem();

//...
//Setters
//..
accountItem.save(); //Make sure you save this registry to your database first.

user.accountItem = accountItem)
user.save();
```

Remember to make 'public' the AccountItem property in the UserItem class

Answer (score 1):

It's been quite while, but anyways... The easiest way to do one-to-many Relationship as suggested by [@satyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31590/satya) at this [issue#60](https://github.com/chennaione/sugar/issues/60#issuecomment-41715251).
Assuming one `User` has multiple `Account`, this can be achieved using custom getter like so:

```
import com.orm.dsl.Ignore;

class User extends SugarRecord<User> {
  private int fieldId;
  private int userId;
  private String name;
  //...
  @Ignore
  private List<Account> accounts;

  public List<Account> getAccounts(){
      return Account.find(Account.class, "user = ?", this.id.toString());
  }  
}

class Account extends SugarRecord<Account> {
  private int userId;
  private String authKey;
  private String authValue;
  //...
  private User user;
}
```

Notice: we can add `@Ignore` because we don't need to persist `accounts` since its handled by the reference `user` in the `Account` class. a simple usage example can be as follow:

```
User admin = new User();
admin.userId = 1;
admin.name= "admin";
if (admin.save()){
  Account a1 = new Account();
  a1.userId = 1;
  a1.user = admin;
  if (a1.save()){
    Log.d("TAG", "Account saved.");
  }
}
```

The one-to-one relationship should be much easier, just use reference field as shown in the [documentation](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/creation.html).

The current version at this time is 1.5.

Hope this helps!